# Face authentication usinf MLKIT android studio

Tags: android-studio, face-recognition, firebase-mlkit

Using mlkit I can able detect the face and also store the face. Now I want to verify the stored face with current face. How to implement in mlkit. I google but I cant. Please suggest how to implement. I prefer only mlkit not any other like opencv,..

Answer (score 2):

MLKit only supports face detection, not face recognition or authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two detected faces by comparing the distance between their facial landmarks, the distance between their facial contours, and the difference in their facial attributes. The threshold values are arbitrary and may need to be adjusted depending on your use case.

```kotlin
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.Face
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceContour

fun compareFaces(face1: Face, face2: Face) {

    // Compare the facial landmarks
    val landmarks1 = face1.landmarks
    val landmarks2 = face2.landmarks

    // Compare the facial contours
    val contours1 = face1.contours
    val contours2 = face2.contours

    // Compare the facial attributes
    val attributes1 = face1.attributes
    val attributes2 = face2.attributes

    // Compare the facial landmarks
    val leftEye1 = landmarks1.get(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE)
    val leftEye2 = landmarks2.get(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE)
    val leftEyeDistance = leftEye1.position.distanceTo(leftEye2.position)

    // Compare the facial contours
    val upperLipBottom1 = contours1.get(FaceContour.UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM)
    val upperLipBottom2 = contours2.get(FaceContour.UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM)
    val upperLipBottomDistance = upperLipBottom1.points.distanceTo(upperLipBottom2.points)

    // Compare the facial attributes
    val smilingProbability1 = attributes1.smilingProbability
    val smilingProbability2 = attributes2.smilingProbability
    val smilingProbabilityDiff = Math.abs(smilingProbability1 - smilingProbability2)

    // Compare all the values and decide if the faces are similar or not
    if (leftEyeDistance < 0.1 && upperLipBottomDistance < 0.1 && smilingProbabilityDiff < 0.1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "The two faces are similar.")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "The two faces are not similar.")
    }
}
```